# How to install Veloview for Velodyne on Rasberry pi 3 model b plus?

Tags: pi-3, pi-3b+, 64-bit

I have installed 64 bit rasberry pi os on rasberry pi model b plus, I have downloaded Veloview tar.gz file from their website that was under the linux 64 bit category. I am worried whether there is problem with the architecture i am using.
`bash: ./VeloView: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Comment: Are you sure that's an aarch64 file? Because I'm not. It's probably an x86-64 architecture.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Can you tell me whether it is possible to install Veloview in Rasberry pi by any other means.